# Binding to an object inside a list of a list

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, maui

I have a list of object A that contains strings and a list of Object B that contains strings

```
public  class ObjectA
{
    public string string1 { get; set; }
    public string string2 { get; set; }
    public ObjectB[] objB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public string string3 { get; set; }
    public string string4 { get; set; }
}
```

how can I bind string3 and/or string4 in my view ?

Before implementing dependency injection of my service I used to do something like this :

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectA}">
  <label Text = "{Binding objB[0].string3}" />
...
```

now it gives me a null reference error in my XAML file :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

what is the best approach to bind to an object inside a list of a list .

Comment: if this syntax used to work, it still should.  If the only thing that has changed in the use of DI, then it stands to reason that the problem is with your DI or data retrieval failing, not your binding expression

Comment: @Jason both the DI and data retrieval are working fine.

Comment: then you need to provide more information.  Which line is causing the exception?  What is the stack trace?  Can you please provide the actual code/xaml in question, and not pseudocode?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve this line what gives null <label Text = "{Binding objB[0].string3}" />

Comment: That’s a start. You’ve omitted too much xaml. Label can’t immediately follow CollectionView declaration. Add what is missing, to make that valid. The concept is to show minimum COMPLETE code. That someone could run themselves.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it is a collection of objects A that each element contain a collection of Object B

Comment: I’ve deleted my comments. I’m sorry, but if you don’t take the time to **edit your question** to show **accurate code**, then it is not possible to help you. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: check if the objectB list inside objectA is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The itemsSource of CollectionView should bind to the type of IEnumerable, specifies the collection of items to be displayed. I made a demo use following code.

For xaml, I bind the ItemsSource to ItemCollection which contains a collection of ObjectA.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="mycoll" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding objB[0].string3}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

In .cs file, set BindingContext:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}
```

In viewModel, I just add some test code:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ObjectA> ItemCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ObjectA>();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        // add some test code
        ItemCollection.Add(new ObjectA
        {
            string1 = "string1",
            string2 = "string2",
            objB = new ObjectB[]
            {
                new ObjectB
                {
                    string3 = "string31",
                    string4 = "string41"
                },
                new ObjectB
                {
                    string3 = "string32",
                    string4 = "string42"
                }
            }
        });
        ItemCollection.Add(new ObjectA
        {
            string1 = "string1",
            string2 = "string2",
            objB = new ObjectB[]
            {
                new ObjectB
                {
                    string3 = "string31",
                    string4 = "string41"
                },
                new ObjectB
                {
                    string3 = "string32",
                    string4 = "string42"
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For more info, you could refer to [Populate a CollectionView with data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it works.